# How does a botnet client gain access to the user's username and password?

Tags: windows, malware

How does a botnet client gain access to the user's username and password?

I assume it must then send these details as well as the user's IP address to the CnC server.

Does it use some kind of phishing method or is the sensitive data easier to access than expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is not really necessary for installed malware to bother to steal your user credentials, but in the case that they did, The passwords of all users are stored in the registry as a hash. Most botnets install RASkits that enable the herders to connect to services on the box without windows passwords.

There are several tools out there for cracking windows authentication hashes. One of the most famous is the venerable [L0phtCrack](http://l0phtcrack.com/) (and the open source [OphCrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/)). Nowadays power tools like [HashCat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcat) are used to crack a wide array of hashes in large volumes.

See more info and step-by-step instructions here: http://www.onlinehashcrack.com/how-to-extract-hashes-crack-windows-passwords.php